# How to display the "instanceof" in symfony2 on screen

Tags: php, symfony

I want to know that my object is the instance of which class.

Like

```php
class user {  }
```

```php
class driver extends user {}
```

I want to find out that when user is logged then whether symfony creates the instance of user or driver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_called_class()` function should do the trick for you.